# Converting a point from Rectangular to Cylindrical Coordinate Systems

Tags: coordinate-systems

I am solving this problem and I am stuck on converting a point from rectangular to cylindrical coordinates.

The answer is from $B(0,5,0)$ to $B\left(5,\frac\pi 2,0\right)$.

The problem is when I try to get $\phi$ which is just equal to inverse tangent of $ \frac{y}{x} $. When I input it, $\tan^{-1} \left(\frac{5}{0}\right)$, I only get math error.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong: strictly speaking, $(r,\varphi)$ is the solution of the (non-linear) system:
$$\begin{cases}r\cos\varphi=x,\\r\sin\varphi=y.\end{cases}$$
with the conditions $r>0,\enspace -\pi<\varphi\le \pi$.

Now this system is equivalent to 
$$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\quad \phi=\arctan\frac yx$$
only if $\;1)\enspace x\neq 0$, $2)\enspace x>0$. If $x=0$, $\dfrac yx$ is undefined, whence the error.

Comment: The answer is given which is stated above. It is in the book. My problem is how did they get that value of phi.

Comment: Like any system of trigonometric equations: if $x=0,\enspace y\neq0$ then $r=\lvert y\rvert$ and the system $$\begin{cases}\cos\varphi=0,\\\sin\varphi=\pm1.\end{cases}$$ has solutions $\;\varphi=\pm\frac\pi2$.

Comment: I dont clearly understand. Thanks.

Comment: Make a drawing with the trigonometric circle: what is the polar angle of a point on the $y$-axis?